# How can I start a new Digital Ocean droplet from Prudentia?

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean, prudentia

I've been an early adopter of [Prudentia](https://github.com/tizianoperrucci/prudentia). Upto now I've only provisioned existing nodes with it.

Now I would like to use it to create a new Droplet and provision that. I'm stuck now because I don't know exactly what strategy to follow. It looks like Prudentia targets pre-started instances only…

Is this possible, has anybody done it before?

Can you share a high level strategy for it and potentially some code samples?

Comment: Haven't done much with Prudentia, but in case you're just interested in simpler Python Digital Ocean API wrappers, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-digitalocean works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can read all about how to do this in an article by [Tiziano Perrucci on the StarterSquad blog](http://www.startersquad.com/blog/simple-deployments-with-prudentia/) basically it's as simple as:

```
prudentia digital-ocean
(Prudentia Digital Ocean) register
…
provision <your-box>
```